# Inductive numerical proof: for k>= 10 it is true that 2^k > k^3

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to prove something, that I thought would be relatively simple.

```
(k≥10 ⟹ 2^(k::nat) > (k::nat)^3)
```

However, I am getting stuck and do not know how to progress.

```
lemma "(k≥10 ⟹ 2^(k::nat) > (k::nat)^3)"
proof (induction k)
  case 0
  then show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc k)
  assume "10 ≤ k ⟹ k ^ 3 < 2 ^ k"
  assume "10 ≤ Suc k"
  show "(Suc k) ^ 3 < 2 ^( Suc k)"
  apply (simp add: algebra_simps)
  then show ?case sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good induction rule can save a lot of hassle. You want to start induction with `10`, not `0`, so maybe there is a better induction rule? Using

```
find_theorems name:ind name:Nat
```

I find this one

```
 Nat.dec_induct: ?i ≤ ?j ⟹ ?P ?i ⟹ (⋀n. ?i ≤ n ⟹ n < ?j ⟹ ?P n ⟹ ?P (Suc n)) ⟹ ?P ?j
```

From now on it is simple equational reasoning, and I was able to follow the proof in [this math stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438335/53195) step by step:

```
lemma 
  assumes "k≥10"
  shows "2^(k::nat) > (k::nat)^3"
using assms
proof(induction rule: Nat.dec_induct)
  case base show ?case by simp
next
  case (step n)
    note power2_eq_square[simp] power3_eq_cube[simp] ring_distribs[simp]
    have "Suc n ^ 3 = 1 + 3*n + 3*n^2 + n^3" by simp
    also have "… < 51*n + 3*n + 3*n^2 + n^3" using `n ≥ 10` by simp
    also have "… = 54*n + 3*n^2 + n^3" by simp
    also have "… < 6*n^2 + 3*n^2 + n^3" using `n ≥ 10` by simp
    also have "… = 9*n^2 + n^3" by simp
    also have "… < n^3 + n^3" using `n ≥ 10` by simp
    also have "… = 2 * n^3" by simp
    also have "… < 2 * 2^n" using `n ^ 3 < 2 ^ n` by simp
    also have "… = 2^(Suc n)" by simp
    finally show ?case.
qed
```

Comment: Hi Joachim, 
Thank you for describing the process as well!

Answer (score 0):

For algebraic proofs, the trick is to exactly identify the simplification steps and then `find_theorems` to search the relevant rules. Algebraic simp set doesn't contain aggressive simplifaction rules, probably because oversimplification might leave the goals unprovable. (Someone can add more reasons)

In this particular case, you have to assume `10 ≤ k` for induction hypothesis to work. You can easily do that by `case_tac "10 ≤ k"`, and then rewriting by `monoid_mult_class.power3_eq_cube` and `le_Suc_ex`. For `¬ 10 ≤ k`, you can prove the goal using `not_less_eq_eq`.